# How do i take value from EditText with button onclick and show it in TextView

Tags: android

How to get data from `EditText` and display that value in `TextView`?

First, i want `TextView` to be hidden by default so i made this

```
Button getTxt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.inputtext);
final TextView fieldText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.filedText);
getTxt.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

getTxt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View view) {
        fieldText.getText().toString();
        getTxt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
});
```

And when i click on  the button, i want to show the text from `EditText`

Why my code isn't working?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try out this:

**Java file:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText editText;
    Button button;
    TextView textView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        editText=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
        button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        textView=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                textView.setText(editText.getText().toString());
            }
        });

    }
}
```

**xml file:**

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=""
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<Button
    android:text="Click here"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="62dp"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:text="some text"
    android:ems="10"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
```

Comment: Thank you, it is working, Could you tell me what i was doing wrong?

Comment: Hi Bokch, i thick you have not initialized the button field

Comment: Button button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button); i think you have not initialized the button field like this.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you are hiding your button not the text view.
You should be doing this: `fieldText.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)`

```
 getTxt.setOnClickListener(
        new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
               String text = fieldText.getText().toString();
               fieldText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
               fieldText.setText(text);

            }
        });
```

This code `fieldText.setText(text);` does the thing.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it doesn't work is : **you are not setting text** to the `TextView`. This should solve it:

```
 Button getTxt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.inputtext);
 final TextView fieldText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.filedText);
 getTxt.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

 getTxt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

     public void onClick(View view) {

         getTxt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
         getTxt.setText(fieldText.getText().toString());
     }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

First declare your EditText

```
 EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText); // put id of editText here
 Button getTxt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.inputtext);
 final TextView fieldText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.filedText);
 editText.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

 getTxt.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                public void onClick(View view)
                {
                   String text = editText.getText().toString();
                   fieldText.setText(text);
                   editText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                }
            });
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Button getTxt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.inputtext);
final TextView fieldText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.filedText);

getTxt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View view) {

        fieldText.setText(getTxt.getText().toString());   

    }
});
```

Do this...